# Save surfaceview to canvas

Tags: android, android-intent, surfaceview, android-canvas, android-file

I'm trying to save a screenshot of my app.
My main screen is a SurfaceView, I'm creating a new canvas and drawing the surfaceview into the canvas. I have a problem because the PNG I get is totally transparent.

Here's my code

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(image);
    draw(c);

    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test2.png";
    File file = new File(path);
    try 
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.setDataAndType(screenshotUri, "image/png");
       startActivity(sendIntent);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ensure that the surface has been fully created by doing this

http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame/androidgame3.html

Try taking your screenshot in the onSurfaceCreated method or else you will get blank until the surface exists.t The documentation says draw() will return nothing until a full layout has been rendered.

Comment: My Surface is created (the game is displayed on the screen ) when I try to take a snapshot.